# Get the selected child within an .each loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each, children

Hey guys. I am trying to get the selected option in an each loop. What is the correct syntax to achieve that?

I tried the following:

```
var row = $('#template_23423);

row.find('select[name^=COUNTY]').each(function (){
    var selectedOption = $(this).children(':selected').val();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var row = $('#template_23423');

row.find('select[name^=COUNTY]').each(function(){
  var selectedOption = $('option:selected', $(this)).val();
};
```

That will give you the value of the `options` if you want to their text, use `text()` instead of `val()`.

Comment: thank you very much! any books you can recommend on jQuery/JS?

Comment: @Kel: I personally love **Learning jQuery**, more details here: https://www.packtpub.com/jQuery/book. And guess what I have learned most of it through stackoverflow :)

Comment: thanks. I am kind of new in jQuery and appreciate everything I can get about it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kel: You are welcome :) Note that if you search on google **Learning jQuery pdf** you will be able to get its free pdf version for download.